# Joining in LINQ to select a sublist within a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, join, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have two classes as follows:

```
public class HRM_SERVICE_PERD_BNFT_DTLModel
{
    public string SRVC_PERD_BNFT_CODE { get; set; }

    public string RTR_BNFT_CODE { get; set; }

    public string RTR_BNFT_NAME { get; set; }

    public string RTR_BNFT_CALC_MODE { get; set; }

    public string SAL_HEAD_CODE { get; set; }

    public string SAL_HEAD_NAME { get; set; }

    public string RTR_BNFT_IN_PERCENT { get; set; }

    public string RTR_BNFT_AMOUNT { get; set; }

    public string RTR_BNFT_INACTV_DATE { get; set; }

    public short? RTR_BNFT_SLNO { get; set; }
}



public class HRM_RETIREMENT_BENEFITModel : BaseModel
{
    public string RTR_BNFT_CODE { get; set; }

    public string RTR_BNFT_NAME { get; set; }

    public string RTR_BNFT_SRTNM { get; set; }

    public string RTR_BNFT_REM { get; set; }

    public short? RTR_BNFT_SLNO { get; set; }


}
```

Now I want to select data from the first model for a specific 'SRVC_PERD_BNFT_CODE', then I need to select the 'RTR_BNFT_NAME'  from the second table for all the filtered data along with some other value from the first model. I'm trying kind of joining, but not getting the name. It's showing system.collection.string instead of value.

Here is what I'm trying so far:

```
public List<HRM_SERVICE_PERD_BNFT_DTLModel> GetBenefitData(string mstcode)
    {
        var model2 = DataContext.HRM_SERVICE_PERD_BNFT_DTL.AsEnumerable().Where(m => m.SRVC_PERD_BNFT_CODE == mstcode).Select(s=>s).ToList();

        var model = DataContext.HRM_SERVICE_PERD_BNFT_DTL.AsEnumerable().Where(m => m.SRVC_PERD_BNFT_CODE == mstcode)
            .Select(s => new HRM_SERVICE_PERD_BNFT_DTLModel
            {
                RTR_BNFT_CODE = s.RTR_BNFT_CODE,
                RTR_BNFT_SLNO = s.RTR_BNFT_SLNO,
                RTR_BNFT_CALC_MODE = s.RTR_BNFT_CALC_MODE,
                RTR_BNFT_AMOUNT = (s.RTR_BNFT_AMOUNT).ToString(),
                RTR_BNFT_NAME = (from x in model2
                                 join c in DataContext.HRM_RETIREMENT_BENEFIT on      x.RTR_BNFT_CODE equals c.RTR_BNFT_CODE into p
                                 from b in p.AsEnumerable()
                                 select b.RTR_BNFT_NAME).ToList().ToString(),

                RTR_BNFT_IN_PERCENT = (s.RTR_BNFT_IN_PERCENT).ToString()
            }).ToList(); 


        return model;
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Following is suspicious.

`.ToList().ToString()`

Remove the `ToString` part and replace it with something like `FirstorDefault`, then it should work.

Reason for getting something like `System.Collection.String` is that `List<T>.ToString()` is usually typename until it is overridden in some way.

Following minimal snipped produce `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]`

```
 List<String> list = new List<String>();
var str = list.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(str); //System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [ System.String ]
```

Comment: after using FirstorDefault I'm getting the name, but only the first name is repeating for every row, but I need to select the corresponding name. How can I do that?

Comment: The problem boils down to getting one string out of string enumeration. You can use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) or Linq [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) to get One string out of enumeration.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get how  String.Join or aggregate can help?

Comment: >>but only the first name is repeating for every row : Does it mean the same set of rows are coming from inner sub query for every row of outer query. You will get first name of inner query result. The query result should be specific only to outer row, (and should not be common to all rows). If it is repeating, consider adding more condition on inner most join `join c in DataContext.HRM_RETIREMENT_BENEFIT on      x.RTR_BNFT_CODE equals c.RTR_BNFT_CODE into p
                                 `

Comment: My query returing the names as a list all right, but since I denfined the 'RTR_BNFT_NAME' as just string not List<string>, so it can hold only one name. I tried to change type of RTR_BNFT_NAME to list, but then getting all the names every time! I need to select the name one after another, should I enumarete manually by using a for each loop here?

Comment: On what basis (filtering criteria) should the name be selected from List<String>. There has to be some criteria, otherwise, it will always be same.